# How should I store text in a selenium test script to output the number of search results found on any search engine?

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, path

I am working on an assignment for a web applications testing class, and the assignment question requires students to write a test script that tests the functionality of any search engine and then stores and outputs the number of search results found.

The search field I am testing is front and center on Yahoo Finance,
https://finance.yahoo.com

I generated a positive test script to test for the functionality of a search term known to produce some non zero results.

I noticed that the xPath generated is dynamic, and wrote the following code after STFW for a tutorial on how to correctly get the CSS path using firebug, there may be an error in this code segment as it is not passing the test:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/" />
<title>Keurig positive</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">Keurig positive</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=UHSearchBox</td>
 <td>keurig</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>id=UHSearchProperty</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
 <td>results</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>                          /*The code that is causing the bug is the next segment*/
 <td>storeText</td>
 <td>css=html#Stencil.NoJs.js.yui3-js-enabled.sa-device-desktop.sa-skin-desktop body#ysch.firefox.gecko.windows.v42_0 div#doc.uh3-p div#bd div#results div#cols div#left div#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_786 ol#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_785.reg.searchBottom li#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_784.first.last div#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_783.dd.pagination.fst.lst.FinPgntn div#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_782.compPagination span#yui_3_10_0_1_1449533426068_781</td>
 <td>numSearchResults</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>echo</td>
 <td>${numResults} total</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears to refer to a dynamic web element, though, that's what I think, based on the lengthy numeric ID that it refers to.

Is there a better way to store and work with the number of search results found? It is a requirement of this assignment.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate your time.

RS

Answer (score 0):

Use the ['multiple elements' finder methods](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) like `find_elements_by_xpath`, instead of `find_element_by_xpath` ('find_element**s**_' vs 'find_element_'). Those return all the elements which match your rule, not just the first. Doing a `len()` of that result tells you how many of those appear on the page. Ensure that your locator is specific to results and not something else on the page. Once you have a list of elements, loop over them and do the necessary actions. Like `print elem.text` to get the text of each result.

Not sure if your *assignment* requires you to click on "Next Page" etc. In that case, go to the next page and re-find the elements and keep adding the number of matches found for each page.

Btw, if your question is about using the right locator for the results, give an example of what you were searching for. I used the xpath locator `//h3/a[contains(@class, 'fz-m')]`.